# using SpeechRecognizerUI in my WP 8 app causing it crash unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, exception, eventhandler

I am new to windows phone app development. I am trying to build a simple speech recognition app using SpeechRecognizerUI class. But the problem is whenever i try to debug the app in my Lumia 520 device(working on 8.1 platform), it load the listener as usual and then debugger stopped automatically at the same time it load within a second, don't allow me sufficient time to speak even a single word. I am googling since 2 days but got nothing helpful. I have provided a single button on "MainPage.xml" of my app for which i have given the following code.

```
namespace Kundali
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ![SpeechRecognizerUI][1] sprec = new SpeechRecognizerUI();
        SpeechRecognitionUIResult result = await sprec.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You said {0} ", result.RecognitionResult.Text));  
    }
}
```

When i tried to handle the exception in catch handler it shows the exception "The text associated with this error code could not be found" not even listening the single text. Some one please help me.

Actually i am working with Visual studio 2012 (Express for windows Phone 8) but my device is on 8.1. Is this the problem?? If yes then please provide the solution. How do i integrate the functionality of 8.1 in vs2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possible causes:

1. Did you add the Speech capability and the Microphone capability in your manifest `WMAppManifest.xml` file?
2. Do you have speech support for your current language? (Try setting to en-US to test)

Comment: Yes i added that. Also when i open it by long holding search key it works fine.  the problem happens when i use my code to launch that.

Comment: Also you need `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE`. If you run under the debugger, you should see the information in the exception (it says you need both capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [TTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207057%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (`Text to Speech`) which is also compatible with `Windows Phone 8.1`?

- [Sample](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/15/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-texttospeech/)
- [Windows Phone 8.1 Text to Speech](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Windows-Phone-81-Text-to-Speech-Speech-to-Text-and-Cortana)

Comment: yes i have already used but that i was used for windows phone 8 nearly a year ago. And it worked fine in 8.1 too. The problem is with the launcher. When i long hold on search it simply open the listener and work fine. But when i tried it with my code it crash. :( Does windows phone 8.1 not support the code used for same in windows phone 8?